# Jenkins(Docker) - PipeLine Error - Unable to deploy application using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to devops and i was trying to created a jenkins pipeline for one my projects.

Error:
[image: Pipeline Error Snapshot]

Details:

Jenkins: Started using following command

```
sudo docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --restart=on-failure jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Docker Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker-compose build --no-cache'
            }
        }
        stage('Docker Up') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker-compose up'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                branch 'develop'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'python main.py'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain and provide a fix for this?

Comment: Please, post code and not screenshots of it

Comment: Added jenkinsfile for reference!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the problem is that you are running Jenkins inside a Docker container and trying to run `docker-compose` from within that container. So you are running a Docker daemon on your host machine and using it to spin up a container that is also trying to run a Docker daemon. The solution here is to use Docker-in-Docker and make your docker-compose run on your host machines Docker daemon instead of the containers Docker daemon. You can find information on how to do this [here](https://medium.com/swlh/quickstart-ci-with-jenkins-and-docker-in-docker-c3f7174ee9ff) under the docker-in-docker section.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your help. I have used "sudo docker run -d  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --restart=on-failure jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11" but still having the same issue.

Comment: I moved to host machine instead of using Docker instance.

Comment: Yes that would solve the problem too